# What does it mean to say that a statement is independent of a theory T?

Tags: logic, model-theory

Let $\phi$ = $\forall x \forall y (x \cdot y = y \cdot x)$. It is sometimes said that $\phi$ is "independent" of the axioms of group theory. What does 'independent' mean $\textit{exactly}$? Is it:

(1) That we can find models of group theory $\mathfrak{M}$ and $\mathfrak{N}$ such that $\mathfrak{M} \models \phi$ but $\mathfrak{N} \models \lnot\phi $

Or:

(2) We cannot derive $\phi$ from the axioms of group theory.

Or: is it the case that (1) and (2) are equivalent?

Comment: The point is that $\phi(x)$ stating that $x$ is abelian is *not* a sentence in the language of groups. It is a sentence *about* groups, as you have $x$ as a variable for the group itself. But you can write the sentence $\phi=\forall x\forall y(x\cdot y=y\cdot x)$ which is independent of the group axioms, and if $G\models\phi$, then we say that $G$ is an abelian group.

Comment: You shoud delete from your post all occurences of $x$. "Is abelian" s a sentence (it has a constant truth value), it does not depend on the elements of the models.

Comment: Thank you for your corrections. I have made the edits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A sentence $\phi$ is independent of $T$ if there are $M,N\models T$ such that $M\models\phi$ and $N\models\neg\phi$. [This is your (1).]

It is a theorem (Gödel completeness theorem) that $\phi$ is independent of $T$ if and only if  $\phi$ and  $\neg\phi$ cannot be derived $T$ in some (here not defined) syntactic calculus.

Comment: Great! Thanks. What is the relationship between Gödel's theorem and another word "undecidability"? It seems to me that Gödel's theorem shows the "undecidability" or certain sentences in syntactic calculus. Do these words "independence" and "undecidability" mean the same thing?

Comment: Gödel's completeness theorem is not related to Gödel's incompleteness on undecidability theorems. The relation between completeness and decidability is to complex to fit in a comment.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean about the complex relation, but it is pretty straightforward to show that a recursively axiomatisable, complete theory is decidable, so for r.a. theories, undecidability implies incompleteness. I am not aware of any implications in the other direction. In general, decidability and completeness are quite different kinds of animals.

Comment: @EricWofsey thank you. I have corrected my answer.

Comment: @tomasz very good (typo: r.e or c.e theories). A self-contained answer would not have fit in a comment, though :)